# List of symbols in dissertation with wide range of topics

Tags: scientific-publishing, science

Currently, I am writing a dissertation in computer science, which covers a relatively wide range of topics.

When creating the List of symbols I have the problem that many symbols appear several times. E.g. [image: alpha] is used for the learning rate in Artificial Neural Networks, for the cooling rate in Simulated Annealing and for a constant in Ant Colony Optimization as multiplier of the distance.

Would you add such symbols to the List of Symbols?

Comment: Could you have a separate list of symbols per chapter/topic, or is that not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you use them the reader needs to be able to look them up and see what you meant when you used them.

Comment: And consider appending the chapter/section (the context) in which the symbol has that meaning.